# Brew is not able to find dependency in spite of it being installed

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

Brew is not able to find dependency inspite of it being installed.
dependency 'urllib2_kerberos' is already installed yet homebrew throws the message

*Homebrew does not provide special Python dependencies; install with:  pip install   urllib2_kerberos*

Here are the setup steps:

```
$ sudo pip2.7 install urllib2_kerberos
```

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   urllib2_kerberos in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib2_kerberos-0.1.6-py2.7.egg

```
$ sudo pip2.7 install urllib2_kerberos  --upgrade
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: urllib2_kerberos in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib2_kerberos-0.1.6-py2.7.egg

```
$ brew install post-review
```

> post-review: Unsatisfied dependency: urllib2_kerberos Homebrew does
>   not provide special Python dependencies; install with:   `pip install
>   urllib2_kerberos` Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Also tried

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

It successfully imports

> Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:04:44)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible
>   Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin Type "help", "copyright",
>   "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   >>> import urllib2_kerberos

(Note: post-review is not on http://braumeister.org/ .
I tapped into another formula repo)

Comment: are you sure that `brew` can find that python package? Looks like brew doesn't know to look here: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Can you show what's in your `PATH`?

Comment: $PATH
-bash: //anaconda/bin:/Users/dutishan/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin: No such file or directory
0c4de9c67ed5:local_proxy dutishan$

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this problem myself. The solution is making sure the dependencies are available in your path.

In my case, I'm running with Anaconda Python and had anaconda2/bin in my path but not anaconda2/lib.

I added the following to my zshrc:

`export PATH="/Users/$ME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Users/$ME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7:/Users/$ME/anaconda2/lib:$PATH"`

Then `source ~/.zshrc` (or your respective shell resource file) and you're good.